# Structuring multi-instance MVC app for client specific features

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, plugins, architecture

I have an MVC solution with the following projects/layers:

- **Core** - Domain Models
- **Business** - Services and other business logic
- **DataAccess** - NHibernate mappings, code and generic IRepository pattern
- **Web** - MVC project

I host this for multiple clients in a multi-instance setup, and offer clients to tailor the app to suit their specific needs.  Most of the time this involves adding a feature that might be suitable to other clients and I enable/disable it with a key/value in the web.config.

Recently though, some clients are asking for very specific functionality that other clients will never need.  I'm trying to work out how to structure that in my app to cleanly separate it as best I can from the standard app.

In an ideal world I'd have a separate project within the solution for that client and have everything live in there, but the features involved will touch every layer of the app: Views, Controllers, Css, Images, new Domain Models, NHibernate Mapping and new Services.

I'm not necessarily looking for a silver bullet here, but I can't seem to find anything on the web that talks about this kind of setup, but surely this is a problem that's been solved before?

If anyone can point me in the direction of ANY articles on this it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean solution for these kinds of requirements would be a **plugin architecture.**

Such solutions can range from moderately complex to very complex depending on the required flexibility and whether or not you need to be able to swap out plugins at runtime.

Independent of the path you choose, you need to introduce interfaces at the places where you want to provide custom behavior. This alone can already be challenging if you didn't design your application for such cases in the first place.

Then, you have a few strategies:

#### Explicit plugin configuration

With this approach, you load some kind of "customer configuration" during application startup and use this to register required plugins.

It helps a lot if you have an explicit, clean [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) and use a powerful dependency injection container (personally I can recommend Autofac, but there are many alternatives.

#### Auto-detection and instantiation of plugins

With this approach, your application finds the plugins automatically (e.g. by looking up assemblies in a specific folder) and loads them. This is more involved, because you need to load assemblies and instantiate classes manually. If you go down this path, [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be worth looking at.